# Camera differences between UIImagePickerController and AVCaptureSession on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I'm trying to build a replacement for **`UIImagePickerController`**, using **`AVCaptureSession`** with **`AVCaptureDeviceInput`** and **`AVCaptureStillImageOutput`**, as input/output respectively.

To preview the camera stream I'm using **`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`**.

It's now working correctly for capturing and storing photos just like the default camera.

However, I found 3 problems I was unable to solve:

- photos captured don't get the same quality the default camera provides
- the viewing/capture angle is shortened, just like using the video capture on the default camera
- no way to control camera specific options like flash

Is there any way to get to the level of **`UIImagePickerController`** using a more customizable approach (i.e. `AVFoundation` or any other)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, maybe you don't need the pixel buffer, maybe just overlay something? If you want to get a high quality buffer like UIImagePickerController so you can make some image processing I don't think is possible(Or at least not easy, because as you said, no flash or focus control public API is available). With AVFoundation you will get **raw** buffers of camera input, so don't expect them to be that good;)

Comment: I needed more customization than an overlay on UIImagePickerController, but if there isn't any other way to get its features, I think I'll have to stick with it... Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out "Session 409 - Using the Camera with AV Foundation" in the [WWDC 2010 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). Based on the video, it *looks* like you can resolve all three of your issues with `AVFoundation`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dead on, donkim! I'm typing this from a Windows machine so I can't test anything at the moment, but I've looked at the PDF of Session 409 and, just like you said, all my 3 issues are addressed and a lot more! Thanks for pointing it out. Saved my day!

Comment: Can now confirm that everything is working as expected, using information from the said WWDC 2010 session. The key lies in using **AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto** and configuring the input **AVCaptureDevice** as needed. Thanks again, @donkim!