# Disabling iOS volume button shutter

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing an iOS app that plays music, while the user takes pictures with the camera using `UIImagePickerController`. However if the user wants to increase the volume, pressing the volume buttons causes a picture to be taken instead. I guess this is because Apple re-purposes the volume buttons to be shutter buttons when the camera image picker is displayed.

Is there a way I can disable the `volume button shutter` in my app, so that the volume buttons will control the volume even if the camera screen is being displayed?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866927/camera-differences-between-uiimagepickercontroller-and-avcapturesession-on-iphon

Answer (score 0):

Repurposing the hardware buttons will get your app rejected:

[program access to iPhone volume buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons)

Comment: Snapchat and many others use the side volume buttons for capturing and other features. So i think those warning is meaningless.